# Having problems utilizing a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have built a component but I am not able to used, I had never encountered a problem like this before.

[image]

I have tried a lot of google and searching but I do not find the solution.

You can see an example app here : https://codesandbox.io/s/somemath-1il3r

Comment: Post a [mcve] *in the actual question*, as text. Offsite links and screenshots don't count. Also read the error message, which tells you exactly what the problem is n

Answer (score 0):

Change `import triangleArea from "./src/components/triangleArea";` to `import TriangleArea from "./src/components/triangleArea";`

Similarly change `<triangleArea />` to `<TriangleArea />`

## Why

Custom [components use `PascalCase`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/jsx/react.html)

Comment: that helped, thank you now I have to remember components must be capital case! thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is because components have to be capitalized. You will have to rewrite your component to have a capitol T